# How to pass date to Controller from UI in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Below is my date object in class.

```
@XmlElement(name = "From", required = true, type = String.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "time")
protected Date from;

@XmlElement(name = "To", required = true, type = String.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "time")
protected Date to;code here
```

When i do static code then it works, like as below,

```
{"from":"2017-10-12 18:19:32.028","to":"2017-10-12 18:19:32.028"}
```

But when i pass dynamic values from dateapicker. It is giving me error.
any idea how to pass date to controller

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide a plunker

Comment: @Ramesh Invalid format: "9/13/2017 23:59:00" is malformed at " 23:59:00"